# How to detect strongest Network adapter( connection) and route all data over that detected strong adapter using .net programming

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, network-programming, ip

I want to design a tool that will let me choose the strongest network adapter( in terms of speed and bandwidth) and Also would like to route all network traffic over that physical adapter.

My way is:

1.Detect Adapter and test it for throughout-speed-bandwidth
2.Check for each incoming packet and route it over that adapter by altering its IP header.

and I know I can take help of IP Helper classes of win32 and route command.

Is there any other easy way to achieve this.

Comment: The 'strongest network adapter' may not be the best choice. The network to which it is attached may be so congested as to make another route a better choice. If there are alternate routes, TCP/IP will already choose the one with the least weight as defined in the routing tables. You seem to be trying to second-guess TCP/IP, or write a router. Buy one.

Answer (score 0):

Generally said, this is not that easy.

**Detection of Bandwidth**

The .NET framework provides [classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.aspx) which give you information about network adapter performance, but as far as I know they only consider the technical specification of the network card itself, not the bandwidth of the connection. However, this may be enough for your purpose.

If you want to detect the bandwith of a connection, you not only have to observe the network adapter and it's capabilities, but also the properties of the connection or even the whole infrastructure (the routing or switching hardware, the cables, the amount of traffic, the utilization and much more). There are powerful frameworks, for example nagios, which perform such monitoring.

Fore the beginning, you could start with analyzing delays in TCP connections or utilizing ICMP echos (pings) for measurement, but be warned, this is not an easy task.

**Routing**

Since you cannot write kernel-mode or driver code in C#, you will have perform "userland" routing, by monitoring the traffic and using a library like WinPcap to send out the network packets to the correct interface. (I assume simply changing the system routes is not enough, since you wrote that you want to route each packet individually).

There is already a library, called [eEx Network Library](http://eex.codeplex.com/), which provides classes and an infrastructure to accomplish such tasks in C#. There also is an example for [routing](http://network.eex-dev.net/index.php?id=64&tx_drwiki_pi1%5Bkeyword%5D=Your%20first%20Router), which you can use as starting point. You can create a custom router by inheriting from the classes Router or DirectInterfaceIO, depending on what suits you best.

Here is an example, which can replace the Router class in the example mentioned above.

```cs
//A simple, custom router
public class CustomRouter : DirectInterfaceIOHandler
{
    //Is called for each frame - place your logic here. 
    protected override void HandleTraffic(Frame fInputFrame)
    {
        //Get the IP frame
        //IPv4Frame ipv4frame = GetIPv4Frame(fInputFrame);
        IPFrame ipframe = GetIPFrame(fInputFrame);

        if (ipframe != null)
        {
            //Iterate over all interfaces.
            foreach (IPInterface ipInterface in lInterfaces)
            {
                //Adjust this condition to check whether ipInterface is the correct interface for this frame
                if (true)
                {
                    //With this overload of send, the interface handles hardware addressing. 
                    ipInterface.Send(fInputFrame, ipframe.DestinationAddress);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```